# css file not found?

Tags: php, css

I want to modify a site but the link to css file is like this

> https://192.168.253.70/ossim/style/av_common.css?t=50e990c674ba3640e69c2ed0b79bbd0b

I don't get were the file css is to modify .. av-commen.css is a php file
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) You question is not quite understandable though...

Comment: What do you mean by _"av-commen.css is a php file"_? And how are we suppose to know where the css is in _your app_? The question is _very_ unclear, it doesn't contain any specific issue and there's nothing for us to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `root directory` of the site. The navigate over `ossim` then click on `style` . Find the file says `av_common.css` and Edit it then finally save it! That's it! Pretty simple.

Comment: the file av_commen.css does not contain css but php code

Comment: ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
header("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");


require_once 'av_init.php';


$only_common = GET('only_common');
$only_common = intval($only_common);
    
//Common CSS styles (by order)

Comment: I'd suggest [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43449542/edit) your question to add in the contents of av_common.css.